# Change hinted type of inherited member

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, warnings, type-hinting

Say I have a type-hinted member of a class, and when I inherit I want to change the hinted type of that member to an inherited type.  Is that possible?

```
class Animal:
    pass

class Dog(Animal):
    def look_for_bone(self):
        print("Found a bone.")

class Home:
    def __init__(self, occupant: Animal):
        self.occupant: Animal = occupant

class Kenel(Home):
    def __init__(self, occupant: Dog):
        super(Kenel, self).__init__(occupant)

        # Here I KNOW that the occupant isn't just an Animal, it's a Dog.
        self.occupant: Dog
        # I've also tried `assert isinstance(self.occupant, Dog)`
        # and `assert isinstance(occupant, Dog)`.

fenton = Dog()
k = Kenel(fenton)
print(type(k.occupant))
# I want my IDE to be able to tab-complete look_for_bone on k.occupant
k.occupant.look_for_bone()
```

The above code generates an IDE (PyCharm) warning on `k.occupant.look_for_bone()`: "Unresolved attribute reference "look_for_bone" for class Animal".  But it runs fine:

```
<class '__main__.Dog'>
Found a bone.
```

Comment: It runs fine because type is checked during runtime. PyCharm has to statically check type which is impossible. This may be a reason but I am also interested in reason of this behavior.

Comment: What type checker are you using (or which version of PyCharm)? This runs fine with the latest version of `mypy`. You can also add `occupant: Dog` as a class variable to `Kenel`.

Comment: @a_guest Pycharm 2019.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations) explicitly mentions that annotating instance variables in `__init__` is allowed this doesn't seem to work in PyCharm. It runs fine with mypy 0.761 though. So I suppose this is a PyCharm specific problem.

Besides annotations in `__init__` one can also annotate instance variable in the class body itself (see again [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations)). This does work with PyCharm. So in order to fix your problem you can use:

```
class Kenel(Home):
    occupant: Dog

    def __init__(self, occupant: Dog):
        super().__init__(occupant)
```

Comment: Thank you!  Seems counterintuitive to me to annotate instance variables in the class body, but PEP 536 does say that and it does work.

Comment: @Cai Well if you think of other languages such as Java or C++ instance variables are also declared in the class body. And `typing` has `ClassVar` in order to avoid ambiguity with class variables.